# SQL Server - Handling rows that cannot be converted

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-insert

Good afternoon all,

I am hoping to acquire some assistance with regards to error handling within SQL server.

So here is the scenario:

I am running an insert into and selecting the necessary columns i require. As part of this process, columns containing dates will be converted from varchar to datetime. The problem I currently have is that some of the dates within the columns of the select statement are failing to convert. What i want to know is, is it possible to complete the insert statement for the rows that can convert and then move the problematic rows to another table? Maybe using a stored procedure?

thanks,

Matt

Comment: Sure this isn't a big deal. You need to use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT. Then insert the rows where that is NULL to your failed table. And insert that where that is not null in your current insert.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I will action accordingly.